# The URL of the website doesn't change from http to https automatically

Tags: website

Hi I am unable to login to this website

```
    https://online.portal.nokiasiemensnetworks.com/
```

as when I click on the login button I get this message two times when I click on **Yes**

A sercurity warning pops everytime suggesting with a message

```
   "the current webpage is trying to open a site in your trusted list sites do you want to allow this?"
```

After clicking on Yes the site doesnot redirect to **https** automatically(as it happens in my office PC). and stays as http(which is currently blocked)

The site uses SiteMinder for Authentication of the credentials. I guess SiteMinder changes https requests to http which gets converted automatically to HTTPS by the browser.

Kindly let me know if there are any settings I am missing in the browser due to which I am unable to login and which it stays as HTTP request.

I have disabled SSL settings at this path, Tools-->internet Options--->Advanced--->Security. Here I disable Use SSL2.0 and SSL3.0. Even though I disable these still I am able to perform https requests

Comment: Actually the network has been hacked, hence we blocked the http requests. We are using IE8, and Windows 7. I have tried to recreate in my PC to have this scenario by disabling SSL, the browser was converting HTTP to HTTPS happily. Do you think that if SSL is disabled, a browser cannot convert the HTTP request to HTTPS. As I have tested, ,

Comment: Please provide all that information in the question itself.  If you have disabled SSL then you will be unable to make a https connection, using any SSL mode that hasn't been enabled.  Blocking http requests to blocking hacking, is like taking a broadsword to a tree, it will eventually cut the tree down, but won't actually do much.

Comment: Please stop providing information in comments.  I want to delete comment questions after they have been provided answers within the question itself.

Comment: I have just edited the question. Please find the info